# How to interpret the salary in this job offer

Tags: australia, salary, job-offer

I received a job offer from an Australian company.

In the offer, it states: "Details of the Offer: $108k Salary Package (AUD); Including super, plus quarterly bonus."

How do I interpret this? Does this mean that I'll receive $108AUD, and then they also include super and bonuses? **Or** does this mean that I'll receive $108AUD, which includes super and bonus?

If the latter, what happens if super increases? Will my weekly check become less?

(FYI super is the Australian equivalent to our 401k)

Comment: If it's truly equivalent to a 401(k), the "super" would be included in the $108k and would be deducted from your weekly (?) paycheck. The quarterly bonus would be on top of that. The company might be able to give you a bonus target or range, at least verbally.

Answer (score 7):

Let's give the important part of the answer first.

**If you are unclear about the terms of an offer, ask the company for clarification.**

Only they can tell you what they actually mean. We can guess, but that won't help you if we guess wrong. The company will be very used to people asking for more details.

Having said that, let me give you my guess.

The $108K includes superannuation payments, and there is a quarterly bonus in addition to that. It's normal in Australia that superannuation is included in salary - the company will pay $108K but deduct the superannuation payments from that, just like they deduct taxes. However there are two indications that the bonus is extra: 1) it says "plus bonus" which means the bonus is additional, and 2) if the bonus is included in the salary then it's not a bonus, it's salary. But let me emphasize again: **ask the company.**

For the record I think the punctuation is bad - I would write "$108K, including super; plus quarterly bonus."

Answer (score -1):

I am from UK but I think the answer would be the same.

The figure is the total including bonus and super.

You need to ask the employer for a breakdown as it will differ between companies, You especially need to ask under what conditions is given and how much, it could be based on company profits or it could depend what you manager thinks of you.

Comment: "Plus" quarterly bonus would indicate to me that bonus is on top of salary.

Comment: @DJClayworth and that shows why you need to ask. I see the semi-colon as a larger separator - the amount is one thing the rest is how it is made up